# Jquery Code Sinppets to Solve

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody tell me what are the possible solutions for these??

Question 1: A web page as a form with the id "my_form" and a few elements with the class "excluded" applied.  How can you make a copy of the form and get rid of all elements with the excluded class, only from the new copy of the form?

Question 2: Examine this code snippet. What do you think it's supposed to do? Why doesn't it work? How would you fix it?

```
$("li").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find("ul")) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "gray");
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    }
});
```

Question 3: A user is complaining that audio is playing even after hitting the play/pause button. Given the below implementation, why would that happen? How would you fix it?

```
// Pause Button Implementation:
$("#togglePlayPause").on("click", function () {
    if (audio.paused === true) {
        audio.play();
    } else {
        audio.pause();
    }
});

// when the current audio has played all the way through, read the next element.
audio.addEventListener("ended", function () {
    if (audio.paused === false) {
        var nextElement = _getNextElement();

        // scroll the page so that the next element we're reading is at the top of the browser window.
        $(window).animate(scrollTop: nextElement.offset().top, 400, function () {
            _playElementAudio(nextElement);
        });
    }
});
```

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Make separate questions for each of your questions.

Comment: **Would this be your class homework?** Aren't at least supposed to attempt to solve it and show how far you were able to go?

Comment: No this is not my class homework. Am trying to solve few snippets for a better understanding of jquery

Comment: The questions are separate for each. I have given it 1, 2 and 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**

```
 $("#form").not(".excluded").clone().appendTo("#anotherForm");
```

Comment: Stop down voting people just on an assumption that he is cheating.  If he is cheating he will never make it in the real world with that attitude.  And that doesn't concern my answer. Thanks

Comment: Despite my views on the homework screaming issue, your answer is incomplete. It answers 1/3 of the questions. That's my reason.

Comment: So you will down vote my answer because it is incomplete?  Last time I checked you weren't my professor. Take your power trip somewhere else.  He asked 3 questions.  I answered one of them.  Are you saying he should have made 3 threads? Has it ever occurred to you that I don't care about the points I'm just trying to help him out and solve a problem.

Comment: People like you need to understand a downvote isn't a slap in the face. I stated my reason, and suddenly it's a powertrip. I don't care that you don't care about points, I care about good questions and answers, not a help vamp site. We have chats for questions like this. Kindly don't make assumptions about my motives :)

Comment: Yes, my downvote has ended the internet. Such clear actions of power tripping!